# Average Clusters of x,y coordinates

Tags: list-manipulation, cluster-analysis

This seems like an easy question but I am a bit rusty with *Mathematica*. I have a list of x,y coordinates and I would like to average the first number of each group. E.g. The mean of 10,9,and 9. And the mean for 5 and 3. Then the average of the y values such that the first value (x,y coordinate) in the new list would be {9.33,33).

```
list = {{{10, 34}, {9, 32}, {9, 33}}, {{5, 18}, {3, 20}}, {{16, 21}}, {{20, 
   33}}, {{21, 18}}, {{6, 26}}, {{23, 22}}, {{15, 35}}, {{19, 
   26}}, {{24, 12}}, {{22, 25}}, {{5, 47}, {0, 47}}, {{5, 34}}, {{16, 
   32}}, {{23, 38}}, {{25, 19}}};
```

Comment: `Map[Mean, N[list]]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
Map[(Total[#]/Length[#]) &, #] &@{{{10, 34}, {9, 32}, {9, 33}},
{{5, 18}, {3, 20}}, {{16, 21}}, {{20, 33}}, {{21, 18}}, {{6, 26}},
{{23, 22}}, {{15, 35}}, {{19, 26}}, {{24, 12}}, {{22, 25}},
{{5, 47}, {0, 47}}, {{5, 34}}, {{16, 32}}, {{23, 38}}, {{25, 19}}}
```

Or more simply

```
Map[(Total[#]/Length[#]) &, {{{10, 34}, {9, 32}, {9, 33}},
{{5, 18}, {3, 20}}, {{16, 21}}, {{20, 33}}, {{21, 18}}, {{6, 26}},
{{23, 22}}, {{15, 35}}, {{19, 26}}, {{24, 12}}, {{22, 25}},
{{5, 47}, {0, 47}}, {{5, 34}}, {{16, 32}}, {{23, 38}}, {{25, 19}}}]
```

Comment: actually Arnoud's comment is much better. the built in `Mean` function can be mapped on the list